# Export SSRS report from SQL 2014 using powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I want to automate the generation of a report from SSRS, export the report to csv and then use this data elsewhere. I have done some research and it appears that newer version of SSRS has exposed API to facilitate this. I would like to know if its possible to get the output of a SSRS report in csv using powershell or other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to automate report generation is to set a report subscription in SSRS which will run the report on a user-defined schedule. You can define the output format (CSV in your case), report parameters, and an output location.

The easiest way to create a report subscription is through the Reporting Services web portal.

PowerShell does have a cmdlet `New-RsSubscription` but you can't create a data-driven subscription this way.

Comment: Hi, What I want to do is export an existing report programmatically onto an excel or csv file.